# Exclude .properties file from maven dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a `SpringBoot 2.2.6` application and I have build a maven dependency which I reference by my `pom.xml` as dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.custom.jar</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-jar</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>it.custom.jar</groupId>
                <artifactId>*.properties</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Inside this `.jar` there is few package and a `configuration.properties` file and, right now, I can't remove it.

Is there some way to exclude classes or single file from a `.jar` like that?

Comment: Simple answer to this: No. You have to change that custom.jar not to include such property file which is usually only within a spring boot app but not in a dependency...

Comment: lol! Yes I suppose... thank you